# Forgotten wallet password (bitcoin-qt)

Tags: wallet, bitcoin-core

I've forgotten my wallets password.  Luckly I haven't got any bitcoins yet, still reading about bitcoins.  My question is, now do I reset or create a new password for my wallet?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no way to reset your wallet's password, as Bitcoin-qt is a local application, not an online service.

In your case, as you have not sent any coins to your wallet, you can delete your wallet and create a new one with a new password.

Your wallet.dat file is located in:

```
C:\Users\YourUserName\Appdata\Roaming\Bitcoin (Vista/Win7)
C:\Documents and Settings\YourUserName\Application data\Bitcoin (Win XP)
~/.bitcoin/ (Linux)
~/Library/Application Support/Bitcoin/ (OSX)
```

**Be careful, and make sure to use a password you can remember or store offline in a secure location next time.**